# retrofit - kotlin - Parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm using mvvm , kotlin , retrofit and courtin in my app . I've done several request and all of them works fine but with this one , I get this error "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter list"

this is my json

```
    {
"roomslist": [
{
"id": "1"
}
]
}
```

these are my models

```
data class RoomsListModel(
    @Json(name = "roomslist")
    val roomsList: List<Rooms>
)

data class Rooms(

    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: String
}
```

this is my api interface :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("getPlaceRooms.php")
fun getPlaceRooms2(@Field("amlakid")id:String):Deferred<RoomsListModel>
```

this is my repository :

```
fun getRooms(
    amlakId: String
): MutableLiveData<RoomsListModel> {
    scope.launch {
        val request = api.getPlaceRooms2(amlakId)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            try {
                val response = request.await()
                roomsLiveData.value = response
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.v("this", e.message);
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Log.v("this", e.message);
            }
        }
    }
    return roomsLiveData;
}
```

when the app runs , it goes into e: Throwable and returns the error

my viewmodel

```
class PlacesDetailsViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val repository = PlaceDetailsRepository()


fun getRooms(amlakId: String):MutableLiveData<RoomsListModel> {
    return repository.getRooms(amlakId)
}
}
```

and this my activity request :

```
viewModel.getRooms(amlakId).observe(this, Observer {
        vf.frm_loading.visibility = View.GONE

        it?.let {
            adapter.updateList(it?.roomsList)
            setNoItem(false)
        }

    })
```

I'm using moshi

I've tried to clean ,rebuild but it doesn't make any different

could you help me ? 
what is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding ? to your Model parameters. Not sure if in your case is the String?. It will ensure that you can have null values on your String

```
val id: String?
```

Please double check, whatever value is missing or null in your case

Comment: should be related to `val roomsList: List<Rooms>?`

Comment: Did you make sure you have the Moshi Converter added?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `@Json` annotation in your `val id: String` declaration?